# How to pass reference to object to a modally presented view controller that is contained inside a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm having an issue passing a reference to a my data object.  The presenting view controller has a reference to the data object.  The modal view controller is hooked up to a navigation controller, and is its root view controller.  Here is how I'm doing it:

Presenting VC:

```
- (IBAction)changeCustomerButtonPress:(UIButton *)sender {    
    UINavigationController *customersNC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"customersNC"];
    SCCustomersVC *customersVC = (SCCustomersVC *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"customersVC"];
    customersVC.dataObject = self.splitVC.dataObject;

    //at this point, customersVC.dataObject exists

    [self presentViewController:customersNC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When the modal VC appears, self.dataObject is nil.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{       
    //self.dataObject is nil here.
}
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does you navigation controller in IB have a root view  controller? If, not it should. But presuming that you have one, you shouldn't be instantiating the SCCustomersVC, because the navigation controller will do that when it's instantiated. To pass the data, just get a reference to that controller with topViewController:

```
SCCustomersVC *customersVC = (SCCustomersVC *)[customerNC topViewController];
    customersVC.dataObject = self.splitVC.dataObject;
```